# Convert JSON String to File in Java

Tags: java, json, spring, amazon-s3

I'm trying to convert an `Object` to `JSON` then convert it to `File`
to be able to send it to AWS S3.

Is there a way to convert the String in the most efficient way?
Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
String messageBody = new Gson().toJson(thisIsADtoObject);
```

And for the S3

```
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(s3BucketName, key, file);
        amazonS3.putObject(request);
```

Comment: It's very much unclear from the code posted here. Could please elaborate by posting some better code snippet that you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, to create a file object to send to AWS, you will have to create the actual file on disk, e.g. with a `PrintStream`:

```
File file = new File("path/to/your/file.name");
try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
    out.print(messageBody);
}
```

**Instead** of using the constructor taking a file, you might want to use the one which takes an `InputStream`:

```
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(s3BucketName, key, inputStream, metadata);
        amazonS3.putObject(request);
```

To convert a String to an `InputStream`, use

```
new ByteArrayInputStream(messageBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

[Link to SDK JavaDoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#PutObjectRequest-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.InputStream-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata-)

Comment: Thaniks for this! Right now I'm getting the error ` No content length specified for stream data.  Stream contents will be buffered in memory and could result in out of memory errors.`
When creating the inputStream and metadata

Comment: I suppose you need to specify the content length of the stream in the metadata object

Answer (score 0):

public class JSONStringToFile {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("Name", "somanna");
    obj.put("city", "bangalore");

    JSONArray company = new JSONArray();
    company.add("Compnay: mps");
    company.add("Compnay: paypal");
    company.add("Compnay: google");
    obj.put("Company List", company);

    // try-with-resources statement based on post comment below :)
    try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/Users/<username>/Documents/file1.txt")) {
        file.write(obj.toJSONString());
        System.out.println("Successfully Copied JSON Object to File...");
        System.out.println("\nJSON Object: " + obj);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier with version 2 of the AWS Java SDK.

If you have converted the object to a JSON String, using GSON or Jackson, you can upload it via:

```
PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(s3Key).build();
s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest, RequestBody.fromString(jsonString));
```

No need to set the content length manually.